# LibGDX: Table is not showing the Texture of an actor I added

Tags: image, libgdx

When I try to add an Actor to the table it won't show. When I add it directly to the stage is does. I dont know what to do.

[image: example code]

Item extends Image.

Comment: Please add your code to the question, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: add as a cell or add as a child ?

Answer (score 0):

`table.addActor(child)` add an actor as a child to your Table but I think you're using Table due to you need some layout so use `table.add(child)` that adds a new cell to the table with the specified actor then you can defined a proper alignment with all object you have.

For debugging purpose you can use `stage.setDebugAll(true);` that draw debug lines for all actors.

```
@Override
public void create() {

     extendViewport=new ExtendViewport(48,80);
     stage=new Stage(extendViewport);
     stage.setDebugAll(true);

     Table table=new Table();
     table.setFillParent(true);

     Texture texture=new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
     table.add(new Image(texture)).row();
     table.add(new Image(texture)).row();
     table.add(new Image(texture)).row();
     table.add(new Image(texture));

     stage.addActor(table);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you haven't packed the table for the stage layout try.

shopTable.pack();